# Need help refining code to run a for loop to summarize economic variables from a csv file?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, loops, csv

I have a csv file with a time series of two economic variables (housing starts and Unemployment). I have a list of calculations and a summary (text) that is written with the output of the calculations (basically summarizing in a paragraph format what the trends are of the data). I would like feedback on how i get I get a for loop to go through each variable in the csv file so i have a summary for each variable as the final output.

I tried applying the basic logic of a for loop but I'm just not sure what i have incorrect. I looked at a number of examples on stackoverflow but nothing seems to fit, I'm sure I'm missing something simple but haven't been using python that long so just not sure at this point.

```py
raw_data = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/J042666/Desktop/2019.03 HOUST and GDP.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)

for i in df:

    freq = "monthly "
    units = " million "
    pos = 1
    colname = df.columns[pos]

    alltime = df.mean()
    low = df.min()
    maximum = df.max()
    today = df.iloc[720]
    one_year = df.iloc[709:721].mean()
    two_year = df.iloc[697:721].mean()
    five_year = df.iloc[661:721].mean()
    one_year_vol = df.iloc[709:721].std()
    two_year_vol = df.iloc[697:721].std()
    five_year_vol = df.iloc[661:721].std()
    today_vs_1 = ((today/one_year) -1)*100
    today_vs_2 = ((today/two_year) -1)*100 
    today_vs_5 = ((today/five_year) -1)*100
    rolling_1 = df.rolling(window=3).mean()
    rolling_2 = df.rolling(window=6).mean()
    rolling_3 = df.rolling(window=9).mean()
    today_vs_1_rolling = ((today/rolling_1.iloc[720]) -1)*100
    today_vs_2_rolling = ((today/rolling_2.iloc[720]) -1)*100 
    today_vs_3_rolling = ((today/rolling_3.iloc[720]) -1)*100
    summary = ("The " + str(freq) + str(colname) + " currently stands at " + str(today) + str(units) + " which compares to the 1,2 and 5 year averages of " + str(one_year) + str(units) + "," + str(two_year) + str(units) + "," + " and " + str(five_year) + str(units) + " respectively. " + " Based on the current " + str(colname) + " levels, that reflects a change of" + str(today_vs_1) + ", " + str(today_vs_2) + " and " + str(today_vs_5) + " respectively." " Since the metric began being tracked, the minimum, maximum and long run average total " + str(low) + str(units) + ", " + str(maximum) + str(units) + " and " + str(alltime) + str(units) + " respectively. " "The 1, 2 and 5 year standard deviation for " + str(colname) + " totals " + str(one_year_vol) + str(units) + " ," + str(two_year_vol) + str(units) + " and" + str(five_year_vol) + str(units) + " respectively." + " Based on the current " + str(colname) + " levels compared to the 3, 6 and 9 month rolling averages, the current level reflects a change of " + str(today_vs_1_rolling) + ", " + str(today_vs_2_rolling) + " and " + str(today_vs_3_rolling) + " respectively.")
print(summary)
```

As I describe above, I am hoping to have code that produces a paragraph summary of the financial metrics i calculate in the for loop for each variable.

Comment: Are you looping over columns or rows? Please provide a small reproducible sample of your data.

Comment: columns. https://github.com/seang700/Economic-Data is the link to the csv file im using.

Comment: Surely `raw_data`  is already a dataframe? I think `df = pd.DataFrame(raw_data)` line is redundant

Comment: thanks erncyp, ill look at simplifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are choosing the entire dataframe rather than each column alone;hence, the analysis you were doing was done for both columns. I also just extracted the values required from your operations rather than keeping the entire text that is printed out from Pandas.

This should work:

```
df = pd.read_csv('2019.03 HOUST and GDP.csv')
df = df.loc[:, ['Housing Starts', 'Unemployment Rate']]

for idx, col in enumerate(df.columns):

    freq = "monthly "
    units = " million "
    colname = col

    selectedCol = df.loc[:, [col]]

    alltime = selectedCol.mean()[0]
    low = selectedCol.min()[0]
    maximum = selectedCol.max()[0]
    today = selectedCol.iloc[720][0]
    one_year = selectedCol.iloc[709:721].mean()[0]
    two_year = selectedCol.iloc[697:721].mean()[0]
    five_year = selectedCol.iloc[661:721].mean()[0]
    one_year_vol = selectedCol.iloc[709:721].std()[0]
    two_year_vol = selectedCol.iloc[697:721].std()[0]
    five_year_vol = selectedCol.iloc[661:721].std()[0]
    today_vs_1 = ((today/one_year) -1)*100
    today_vs_2 = ((today/two_year) -1)*100
    today_vs_5 = ((today/five_year) -1)*100
    rolling_1 = selectedCol.rolling(window=3).mean()
    rolling_2 = selectedCol.rolling(window=6).mean()
    rolling_3 = selectedCol.rolling(window=9).mean()
    today_vs_1_rolling = ((today/rolling_1.iloc[720]) -1)*100
    today_vs_2_rolling = ((today/rolling_2.iloc[720]) -1)*100
    today_vs_3_rolling = ((today/rolling_3.iloc[720]) -1)*100
    summary = ("The " + str(freq) + str(colname) + " currently stands at " + str(today) + str(units) + " which compares to the 1,2 and 5 year averages of " + str(one_year) + str(units) + "," + str(two_year) + str(units) + "," + " and " + str(five_year) + str(units) + " respectively. " + " Based on the current " + str(colname) + " levels, that reflects a change of" + str(today_vs_1) + ", " + str(today_vs_2) + " and " + str(today_vs_5) + " respectively." " Since the metric began being tracked, the minimum, maximum and long run average total " + str(low) + str(units) + ", " + str(maximum) + str(units) + " and " + str(alltime) + str(units) + " respectively. " "The 1, 2 and 5 year standard deviation for " + str(colname) + " totals " + str(one_year_vol) + str(units) + " ," + str(two_year_vol) + str(units) + " and" + str(five_year_vol) + str(units) + " respectively." + " Based on the current " + str(colname) + " levels compared to the 3, 6 and 9 month rolling averages, the current level reflects a change of " + str(today_vs_1_rolling[0]) + ", " + str(today_vs_2_rolling[0]) + " and " + str(today_vs_3_rolling[0]) + " respectively.")
    print(summary)
```

Comment: Thank you Tabbakhh....very quick reply. I plugged this in and I get an error that reads: "index out of bounds"....Is that because the calculations are pulling the wrong metrics from the df?

Comment: @seang700- I downloaded your csv file and tested the code and everything worked fine. I am assuming that the csv is not formatted properly and will edit my answer accordingly and hopefully it works.

Comment: @seang700 - No problem, try the newly edited answer.

Comment: @seang700 - No problem! Please choose my answer as a correct answer for this post :)